# How can generate a swagger from my spring boot application?

Tags: spring, rest, swagger

I have created a web rest API using Spring boot and I would like to generate a swagger page with the APIs documentation. How can I do that?

Comment: You are looking for https://springdoc.org/. You can generate an OpenAPI document (and consume it with a Swagger HTML page)

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. It works great. thanks

Comment: i will post an answer below, just for completeness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Spring project dedicated to this: https://springdoc.org/.
You can annotate your classes and an OpenAPI document will be generated from them.

The OpenAPI document can be consumed in many ways (one of those is the Swagger UI, another is to generate clients from it).